# Wordpress / Visual Form Builder Pro

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 3 different forms using VFB, and when submitted they will send an email to the site admin with all the filled out fields. However, I dont want all the fields to be sent in the email, only 4 out of about 20.

I tried using a conditional:

```
if($field->field_id == '39' || $field->field_id == '41' || $field->field_id == '42' || $field->field_id == '96')
```

this works, but all the fields on all the other forms are not being sent.

Then i tried to use:

```
$hidden_field_types = array( '39', '41', '42', '96');

if ( ! in_array( $field->field_id, $hidden_field_types ))
```

Wont work. Displays all fields. Without the !, does work. So, I'm bewildered.

Here is the original email.php that processes the form:

http://pastebin.com/W8bPZSNJ

Line 519 is where I believe the loop to create the email content is.

Comment: Please add your answer as an actual answer (and accept it), rather than an unreadable comment.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. In case anyone is interested:

```
$hidden_field_types = array( '40','44','45','46','50','51','52','53','69','70','71','72','76','77','79','80',‌​'81','85','86','87','88','89','97','98','99','100','102','103','104','107','108',‌​'109','110','128','130','131'); 

// Don't add certain fields to the email

if ( ! in_array( $field->field_id, $hidden_field_types ) == TRUE ) :
```